# Sort Array based on value in java

Tags: java, arrays

Peace and blessing be upon you.

Say I have:

```
int[] array = {1,3,5,2,9,7,0};
```

Simply wanna sort this as:

```
{0,1,2,3,5,7,9};
```

Comment: Use Arrays.sort(array)

Comment: `Arrays.sort(array)`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
int[] array = {1,3,5,2,9,7,0};
Arrays.sort(array);
```

You will need to import java.util.Arrays

Answer (score 0):

use Arrays class of collection framework

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class TestArray {
public static void main(String arg[]) {
int[] array = {1,3,5,2,9,7,0};
System.out.println("before sort : "+Arrays.toString(array));    
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println("after sort"+Arrays.toString(array));    

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Arrays class :

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

:-)